# Shopware 6: Is it possible (atm) to override or better extend an existing element (twig file) via plugin?

Tags: twig, shopware

I want to override or extend the element "image" ("..administration/src/module/sw-cms/elements/image"). Is it possible at the moment? First I want to extend or override the .../config/sw-cms-el-config-image.html.twig template, so I created the file in my plugin (MyPlugin/src/Resources/app/administration/src/module/sw-cms/elements/image/config/), but with no effect.

```
{% block sw_cms_element_image_config %}
    test...
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You would need to `embed` the original file first. Make sure the blocks exists in the original file though

Comment: You mean sw_extends?  I don't know the path. But if I want to override not extend, then I don't need sw_extends?

Answer (score 0):

Your path is wrong. Twig blocks need to be in:
MyPlugin/src/Resources/views/storefront (from here the sames tree like Shopware).

In App you put stuff like scss and js.

Comment: What about admin templates ? Your path is wrong there, or ?

Comment: Yes, instead of view it is app :) The exact path sometimes changes depending on updates. I recommend got to the shopware vendor folder and follow the path:
vendor/shopware/storefront.. 
/view
/app